# Each child in a list should have unique key prop and my browser router is also undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How to clear this problem.
Error in browser router
http://localhost:3000/Questions/undefined and

Each child in a list should have unique key prop.

```
import React from 'react'
import Questions from './Questions'

const QuestionList = ({questionsList}) => {
 return (
<>
     {
      questionsList.map((question)=>(
        <Questions question={question} key={question.id}/>
      ))
     }
</>
 )
}
```

I am trying to build the new component page,i am expected that new component page is created,but as the result is Each child in a list should have unique key prop and my browser router is also undefined.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We can't really help with the router issue because you've not added any code related to that, and the code you have added doesn't seem to reflect the error re keys as you have a key on each mapped component. Are you sure it's that component that's giving the warning? Also shouldn't the `Questions` component just be called `Question` (singular)?

Comment: I guess that `question.id` is not unique or it's `undefined`

Comment: Yeah ,I changed that question.id to question._id .Now it's works!